# online estimation of a servo motor transfer function

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

I am trying to get an online servo motor transfer function, it's a smart servo motor which means that it has position feedback.
the servo motor feedback angle is from 0 to 300 degree through a poteniometer.
i am using an arduino, the servo motor library is installed, i am controlling the servo motor using serial communication protocol and i am getting the servo angle with the same protocol.
i am sending pwm effort 0-1023 pulses (forward).
i want to ask about the simulink input, i am using signal builder as input with a variable signal from 0-5v as show in the attached figure.
if I use this input, I am not able to estimate the transfer function using system identification, I am getting a very low fitting percent as show in the attached figure.
does anyone have an idea how figure this out ?
Thank you!
Here is the figures link :
https://github.com/Zaki23madrid/Images

Answer (score 0):

System identification is done to find a dynamic relationship between an input signal and an output signal. There are some typical signals to conduct identification. The simplest of them is the impulse signal, some servo drivers utilize this sort of signal in their auto-tuning procedures. For high bandwidth servo control systems, the "chirp" signal is typically employed. The chirp signal's both magnitude and frequency increase over time, making it possible to keep the signal-to-noise ratio somewhat stable while spanning the probable operation region in the frequency domain.

All that is to say that, your input signal is not suitable for identification at all. You can very easily create a chirp signal from the Simulink library. Even a chirp up to 100 Hz should yield a functioning model. Also, you can inspect your identified models further by using the compare() function, which shows you how exactly the identified model output matches experimental data.

Comment: Hi,
Where can I find this compare() function?

Comment: Hi, you can find it here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/compare.html

Comment: Hi, I have to compare the motor position right (outpu)? please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It depends on how you wish to model your motor. If you're trying to obtain the relationship between the input torque vs the output position for instance, then yes you will compare the output position. In order to use the compare function, you will need to create an iddata object first, you can follow steps in the documentation from there. Refer to the following link for iddata: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/iddata.html

Comment: I am trying to send a PWM signal to get the motor position, I am using Serial communication protocol to send & receive servo parameters. For the chirp signal block, the frequency target time is set to 100HZ, target time is 100s and initial frequency is 0.1HZ, this parameters doesn't turn on the servo motor, I think it's because of the higher value that chirp signal which is 1, it doesn't turn on the servo motor....